# Ionic change back button default navigation target

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

By default the back button will go the second page if a user is at 3rd page.

How to change the back button target so that the user will go to somewhere else like go back to the first page?

```
//what should I do before or after this code?
$state.go('app.mythirdPage');
```

Answer (score 0):

In ionic the state is created as a stack ( In ionic tab app its multiple parallel stacks for each tab) and every time you navigate to a new state, that is `pushed` to the stack and every time you go back its `popped` out from the stack. So in order to handle the pop of the states and the number of states to be popped, you can use the `$ionicHistory` service's `goBack()` method. It accepts a negative integer as the count of states to navigate back to.

```
// To navigate from 3rd state to first
$ionicHistory.goBack(-2);
```

For more details refer: http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicHistory/